# google app script] How to create non-hacking code using spreadsheet addresses

Tags: google-apps-script

I make and sell spread sheets using google app script.

Every program I sell makes it workable only on that address.

```
  var sheetvalue = "1K113gwapnZwvLwe9Ad9d8Uk68wNVxLWlboku4BzljS5k";
  var actualSheetName  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
  if(actualSheetName!=sheetvalue){
    return;
  }
```

And I try to make it available only for a certain period of time.

```
  var yyyy= 2111;
  var mm = 10;
  var dd = 21;
  var now = new Date()
  var end = new Date(yyyy , mm-1 , dd+1 )
  if(end.getTime() - now.getTime() < 0){
    return;
  }
```

They both work well.

You should know that I obfuscate the code when I distribute it.

It is difficult to modify obfuscated codes when extending the period used later use.

So I just want to exclude the code that checks the period.

(It obfuscates this, too.)

```
function check_date(){
var yyyy= 2111;
var mm = 10;
var dd = 21;
var now = new Date()
var end = new Date(yyyy , mm-1 , dd+1 )
if(end.getTime() - now.getTime() < 0){
return "NO";
}
}
function body(){
var check =check_date();
if(check =="NO"){
return;
}
//...do programm stuff

}
```

But when the user debugged the script. The user can see that the YES,NO value is the key value.

The user can then delete the check_date() code and recreate it.

So I'm going to put a secret code

```
function password(){
var password = "20220105/K113gwapnZwvLwe9Ad"//yyyy mm dd
return password;
} // It doesn't obfuscate.

function body(){

var getpassword_and_date =  password();
var rawdata = getpassword_and_date.split("/");
var getdate = rawdata[0];
var getpassword = rawdata[1];


var id = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId(); 
//like a3igia9we0fjawiegdkf
// do Decryption
.
var makepassword = id+getdate+"secret-key";
makepassword= makepassword.md5();
//it not real code but do like this

if(makepassword!=getpassword){
return;
}

var now = new Date()
var end = new Date(yyyy , mm , dd )
if(end.getTime() - now.getTime() < 0){
return;
}// and date check not real do parse in get date
```

This is good.

Because it can be used only by changing the password key.

But I have a question.

Can the user know the secret key below the code obfuscated by google app script debugging?

```
var makepassword = id+getdate+"secret-key";
```

If the user can figure it out, is there a way to make it impossible?

Comment: If you give a user edit rights to a spreadsheet, then they have every ability (and right) to modify the code of the bound script. You cannot prevent that while using bound scripts. Even if you place the checks inside an attached library and use private methods inside the library to prevent the user from seeing the code, they can still remove the code that calls the library. So instead, either create an add-on (which will not allow users to modify the script) and authenticate users with OAuth, or adopt a reasonable pricing model so your customers want to keep doing business.

Comment: tehhowch// thank for answer i know that so i do obfuscat with this site https://javascriptobfuscator.com/Javascript-Obfuscator.aspx . a...nd can you answer my post? i want close it

Comment: I'm telling you that your current approach can never be user-proofed. Any user with edit rights can **always** debug and alter bound scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @tehhowch has said in the comments you cannot obfuscate the code and expect it to be user-proofed.

What you can do is to publish your code as [library](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries) so the user is not able to see the implementation details. Also take a look at the [private functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#private_functions).

Also look at this Stack question [Apps Script Private functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29014087/apps-script-private-functions).