# _ in variable name google apps script?

Tags: variables, google-apps-script

Declaration code:

```
var isError_ = isError_ || false;
```

In the above declaration, there is an underscore at the end of the variable name. I have read something about underscore in the end (has some purpose). But I can't recall what that is.

Comment: See answer at: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29014087/apps-script-private-functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29014087/apps-script-private-functions)